# Retrieve Status of Rows Processed for long query using PYODBC / SQLAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have several SQL queries that I run regularly but can take a while to complete. I've noticed that different applications which query SQL Server might show a status update (E.g. 1200 rows received).

I was wondering if within SQL Alchemy or PYODBC there was a way to retrieve this, perhaps treat the query as a threaded worker and poll it as it completes.

Thanks,

Comment: If you want the number of rows after it's completed then you need [`cursor.rowcount`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#rowcount). If you want how many rows have been received while the query is running, just increment a variable on each loop of `fetchone`